# Internal signal type error in Test Bench VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I want use internal signal of tag_mem entity in vivado in Test Bench.

Line with error in *TB_tag_mem.vhd*:

```
    alias chTagMem is << signal .tag_mem.chTagMem : chTagMem_line >>;
```

Signal in tag_mem (*tag_mem.vhd*):

```
    type chTagMem_line is array (natural range <>) of std_logic_vector (TAG_WIDTH downto 0);
    signal chTagMem     : chTagMem_line(CHAN_CNT - 1 downto 0);
```

When I run simulation, I see error in *elaborate.log*:

```
Starting static elaboration
ERROR: [VRFC 10-3763] type error near 'chtagmem' ; expected type 'chtagmem_line' [C:/Users/Mixen/CBDD/tag_mem/tag_mem.srcs/sim_1/new/TB_tag_mem.vhd:68]

ERROR: [XSIM 43-3321] Static elaboration of top level VHDL design unit tb_tag_mem in library work failed.
```

How fix this?

#### Reproduce

*TB_tag_mem.vhd*

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.NUMERIC_STD.all;

entity TB_tag_mem is
--  Port ( );
end TB_tag_mem;

architecture Test of TB_tag_mem is

    component tag_mem is
    Port ( 
        clk : in STD_LOGIC
    );
    end component;
        
    -- for check
    type chTagMem_line is array (natural range <>) of std_logic_vector (5 downto 0);
    alias chTagMem is << signal .tag_mem.chTagMem : chTagMem_line >>;
    
begin
   sim: process begin
        report "TEST: Init";
        wait;
    end process sim;

end Test;
```

*tag_mem.vhd*

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity tag_mem is
    Generic (
        WIDTH: integer := 5
    );
    Port ( 
        clk : in STD_LOGIC
    );
        
end tag_mem;

architecture Behavioral of tag_mem is
    type chTagMem_line is array (natural range <>) of std_logic_vector (WIDTH downto 0);
    signal chTagMem     : chTagMem_line(4 downto 0);

begin
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Vivado is complaining about the types because they cannot be exactly the same - the object you are fetching with the external reference will not be the local type. The type needs to be available in a package so that both objects are using the exact same type.

Comment: @Tricky, It turns out that I need to create a package with this type?

Comment: The design hierarchy for tb_tag_mem doesn't instantiate tag_mem which is referenced in the external name path. Not quite a minimal, complete, and verifiable example. Should someone demonstrate a fix using a package containing an unbound definition with an unconstrained element subtype for type chtagmem. The sim process isn't needed to demonstrate the error and doesn't evaluate the external name. If it did tag_mem would be required to have been elaborated first.